# Uniform continuity : stuck at an intermediate step

Tags: uniform-continuity

$$f(x)= \frac{x}{1+x^2}, \, x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I have proved till the following step. I can't understand how do I proceed further. Please help $$f(x)\le|(x-y)||1-xy|$$

Comment: $| f(x) - f(y)| = |(x-y)(1-xy)/(1+x^2)(1+y^2)| \le | (x-y)(1- x^2)/(1+x^2)(1+x^2)| \le |x-y|$ ( $ x \le y$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $x \in \mathbb{R},$ we have

$$f'(x) = \frac{1 - x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} $$

For $|x| \leqslant 1$ we have

$$|f'(x)| = \frac{1 - x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} \leqslant 1,$$

and for $|x| > 1$ we have $|f'(x)| \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$ and local maxima at $x = \pm \sqrt{3}$ where $f'(\pm \sqrt{3}) = 1/8.$

Since the derivative is bounded, $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Alternatively, following your approach

$$\left|\frac{x}{1+x^2} -  \frac{y}{1+y^2}\right| = |x-y|\frac{|1  - xy|}{1 + x^2 + y^2 +x^2y^2} \leqslant |x-y|\frac{1  + |xy|}{1 + x^2 + y^2 +x^2y^2}. $$

I'll leave it to you to show that the RHS is bounded by $C |x - y|$ where $C$ is a constant.

Hint:

If $|xy| < 1$ then

$$\frac{1  + |xy|}{1 + x^2 + y^2 +x^2y^2} < \frac{2}{1 + x^2 + y^2 +x^2y^2}$$

If $|xy| > 1$ then

$$\frac{1  + |xy|}{1 + x^2 + y^2 +x^2y^2} < \frac{2|x||y|}{x^2 + y^2}$$

Comment: shouldnt it be like this???$$|f'(x)| = \frac{x^2 - 1}{(1+x^2)^2} \leqslant  \frac{x^2}{(x^2)^2} = \frac{1}{x^2} $$

Comment: You have an error in your post.  That should be $|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant |x-y||1 - xy|$.  But you need to keep the denominator $1 + x^2 + y^2 + x^2y^2$ as I have done to make sure you can bound that.

Comment: I took $$x=3$$ in the $$|f'(x)| = \frac{x^2 - 1}{(1+x^2)^2} \leqslant  \frac{x^2}{(2x^2)^2} = \frac{1}{4x^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{4}.$$ it comes out as $$0.08\le.028$$

Comment: I appreciate your efforts :)

Comment: The upper bound $$|f'(x)|\leqslant\frac1{4x^2}$$ for $|x|>1$, is wrong.